# Error in PDO/PHP code when connecting to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I am trying to use PHP and PDO in order to create and connect to the MySQL database I have already created.  Everything is working fine except that I keeps giving me this error:

> Connection failed:PDO::__construct(): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: invalid error mode

Can someone please tell me what this error means. Thanks.

EDIT: Here is the draft code.

This is connection.php

```
<?php
class Config
{
    public function Con()
    {
        $config = new Config();
    }
}
class Connection
{
    protected $db = null;
    public function Open()
    {
        try {
            $dsn = "mysql:dbname=cashgroup;
            host=localhost";
            $user = "root";
            $password = "newpassword";
            $options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => 
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE
            );

            $this -> db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password,      $options);

            return $this -> db;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo 'Connection failed:' . $e ->getMessage();
            }
        }
        public function Closed()
        {
            $this -> db = null;
             return true;
        }
}
?>
```

and this is include.php

```
<?php
 include 'connection.php';

try {
    $conec = new Connection();
    $con = $conec -> Open();
    if ($con) {
        echo 'connected';
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `clients`(`name`, `email`) VALUES    (`FakeName`, `fakeemail@gmail.com`)";
        $re = $con -> query($sql);
    } else {
        echo $con;
    }
 }

catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo $ex -> getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Please share the draft code which generates the error to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You've messed up the attributes here:

```
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => 
   PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE
);
```

They should be something like this:

```
$options = array(
   PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
   PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
);
```

Or any other valid values.